# Strip Non-Alphanumeric Characters from an NSString

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nscharacterset

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to strip non-alphanumeric characters from an `NSString`. Probably something using an `NSCharacterSet`, but I'm tired and nothing seems to return a string containing only the alphanumeric characters in a string.

Comment: +1 for being one of the 5% of questions properly tagged as cocoa and not objective-c

Answer (score 149, accepted):

We can do this by splitting and then joining. Requires OS X 10.5+ for the componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:

```
NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSString *strippedReplacement = [[someString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: What are alphanumeric characters? E.g. would German "Umlaute", like ä, ö or ü be included in the set and hence not be trimmed?

Comment: To handle accented characters you need to create a NSMutableCharacterSet that is a union of alphanumericCharacterSet and nonBaseCharacterSet, and invert that

Comment: The `trimmedReplacement` is misleading. In all iOS NSString invocations, *trimmed* means from start and end. May I suggest **occurrencesReplacement** or **strippedReplacement** instead?

Comment: @Erik, umlauts would be included. that makes it unusable for filenames :(

Comment: @datayeah No worries, just change the first line to invert the 'Portable Filename Character Set' as per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_277: `NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789._-"] invertedSet];`

Answer (score 22):

In Swift, the `componentsJoinedByString` is replaced by `join(...)`, so here it just replaces non-alphanumeric characters with a space.

```
let charactersToRemove = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet
let strippedReplacement = " ".join(someString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charactersToRemove))
```

---

For Swift2 ...

```
var enteredByUser = field.text .. or whatever

let unsafeChars = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet

enteredByUser = enteredByUser
         .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(unsafeChars)
         .joinWithSeparator("")
```

If you want to delete just the one character, for example delete all returns...

```
 enteredByUser = enteredByUser
         .componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
         .joinWithSeparator("")
```

Answer (score 19):

What I wound up doing was creating an NSCharacterSet and the `-invertedSet` method that I found (it's a wonder what an extra hour of sleep does for documentation-reading abilities). Here's the code snippet, assuming that `someString` is the string from which you want to remove non-alphanumeric characters:

```
NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove =
[[ NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet ] invertedSet ];

NSString *trimmedReplacement =
[ someString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove ];
```

`trimmedReplacement` will then contain `someString`'s alphanumeric characters.

Comment: FYI, stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: only removes characters from the beginning and end of the string. Maybe that's what you wanted.

Comment: Hmm, good point, Ken. I didn't know that. It still works for my needs, but that's good to know.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 version of accepted answer:

```
let unsafeChars = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted
let myStrippedString = myString.components(separatedBy: unsafeChars).joined(separator: "")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5, Extension:**

```
extension String {

    /// Will strip all non alpha characters from a string
    public var alpha: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Cleanup Category

I have a method call `stringByStrippingCharactersInSet:` and `stringByCollapsingWhitespace` that might be convenient to just drop-in.

```
@implementation NSString (Cleanup)

- (NSString *)clp_stringByStrippingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
{
    return [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}

- (NSString *)clp_stringByCollapsingWhitespace
{
    NSArray *components = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    components = [components filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self <> ''"]];

    return [components componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a Swift version of [Cameron’s category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606211/253485) as an extension:

```
extension String {

    func stringByStrippingCharactersInSet(set:NSCharacterSet) -> String
    {
        return (self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(set) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
    }

    func stringByCollapsingWhitespace() -> String
    {
        var components:NSArray = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self <> ''", argumentArray: nil)
        components = components.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)

        return components.componentsJoinedByString(" ")
    }
}
```

Comment: `"".join(componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(set))` is even better.

Answer (score 0):

The plain cycle would be the faster execution time I think:

```
@implementation NSString(MyUtil)

- (NSString*) stripNonNumbers {
    NSMutableString* res = [NSMutableString new];
    //NSCharacterSet *numericSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    for ( int i=0; i < self.length; ++i ) {
        unichar c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) // this looks cleaner, but a bit slower: [numericSet characterIsMember:c])
            [res appendFormat:@"%c", c];
    }
    return res;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a more effective way than the provided answer**

```
+ (NSString *)alphanumericString:(NSString *)s {

    NSCharacterSet * charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSMutableString * ms = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[s length]];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
        unichar c = [s characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![charactersToRemove characterIsMember:c]) {
            [ms appendFormat:@"%c", c];
        }
    }
    return ms;

}
```

or as a Category

```
@implementation NSString (Alphanumeric)

- (NSString *)alphanumericString {

    NSCharacterSet * charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSMutableString * ms = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[self length]];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.length; ++i) {
        unichar c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![charactersToRemove characterIsMember:c]) {
            [ms appendFormat:@"%c", c];
        }
    }
    return ms;

}

@end
```