# Removing All special character except + - operator from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I want to remove all special character **except +, space and -** . How it is possible?

My string is

```
Äî;a[bRa]Co-Founder MobÄ: +91 9711700008
```

output:

```
abRaCo-Founder Mob +91 9711700008
```

According to Answer below, I update my code but still no success.

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *special = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+ -"];
[special formUnionWithCharacterSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]];


NSString *temp=@"gaurav 1!@#!#@! kant !@#!@#!@#12kestwal ";

NSString *yourString = [temp stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:special];

NSLog(@"%@",yourString);
```

I missing anything?

Comment: For special character, do you mean all non letters characters, so all characters outside 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '0'-'9' ??

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri yes i wants remove all, except a to z, A to Z ,0 to 9 and '+' '-'

Comment: update my code already, please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

BOOL isWanted(unichar character)
{
    if(character>='a' && character<='z')
        return YES;
    if(character>='A' && character<='Z')
        return YES;
    if(character>='0' && character<='9')
        return YES;
    if(character=='-' || character=='+')
        return YES;
    return NO;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString* string= @"Äî;a[bRa]Co-Founder MobÄ: +91 9711700008";
        NSMutableString* filteredString=[NSMutableString new];
        for(NSUInteger i=0; i<[string length];i++)
        {
            unichar character=[string characterAtIndex: i];
            if(isWanted(character))
                [filteredString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c",character]];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",filteredString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The isWanted function returns YES if you want to have that character in string.For legibility I didn't use a lot of logic OR's but just if's, you can replace that with an unique if.
Sometimes if watching the documentation takes too much time, you can invent the solution yourself.Many people will disagree, of course a solution with a single line is better, but if you don't find the right documented method why losing time?

Comment: Thanks.. +1 for your perfect code, It removes all the unwanted Special Symbol

Comment: it's unsafe -- very. it fails for multibyte chars. see the characterAtIndex docs

Comment: What do you mean that it fails for multiple chars? It throws an exception in the case that the range is outside string bounds, but with the for loop is guaranteed that this will not happen.

Comment: not multiple chars but multiBYTE -- see the docs for characters of NSString

Comment: True, characterAtIndex returns an unichar, didn't see it.An implicit cast was made, so the new string could have been dirty of also some unwanted characters, but printed like ASCII character (with no risk of segmentation fault).I edited the code.

Answer (score 2):

much shorter than the mega func. :D above:

```
id s = @"$bla++$bleb+$blub-$b";
NSMutableCharacterSet *ch = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[ch invert];
[ch removeCharactersInString:@"+-"]; //make sure its not removed
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:ch] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@ - %@",ch, s);
```

in this example the $ is removed

Comment: Thanks,,, I am trying this also

Comment: This won't work with the op's example, because letters with diacritical marks are part of the alphanumeric character set.

Comment: He wants those removed, not kept. Look at his example.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri / rdelmar it works perfectly. he asked to remove ALL symbols EXCEPT + and - -- which is what I do :D

Comment: I could use the sumbolCharSet instead but this shows an approach I would propose and I find superior to a loop over chars

Answer (score 0):

could you please try,

```
NSString *yourString = @"Äî;a[bRa]Co-Founder MobÄ: +91 9711700008"

// thanks for Daij-Djan to point my mistake here
NSMutableCharacterSet *special = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[special invert];
[special removeCharactersInString:@"+ -"]; 

// for this one I answer before Daij-Djan, please see edit version
//  note: I didn't offensive to anyone, please do not misunderstanding, thanks.
NSString *yourString =[[yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:special]
 componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

So, it separated and then join, thanks for this link [Strip Non-Alphanumeric Characters from an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656410/strip-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-an-nsstring)

Comment: thanks for reply. It is hard to predetermine all the special characters in my string, How I can remove all special symbol except + - and space?

Comment: trim is wrong.. it trims you want to rm all from beginning end only

Comment: wait for me a bit, I won't give up

Comment: @piam code is not working for me :(    NSMutableCharacterSet *special = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+ -"];
    [special formUnionWithCharacterSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
   
    
    NSString *temp=@"gaurav 1!@#!#@! kant !@#!@#!@#12kestwal ";
    
    NSString *yourString = [temp stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:special];

    NSLog(@"%@",yourString);

Comment: do you try my update one? please see the latest update, the code that you post I still see you use trimming

Comment: @piam thanks for your help,  your solution  is good. but not 100 % accurate, few special symbol like Äî still there.

Comment: @Gryphon  Arggh.. almost there, but anyway your welcome and more than willing to help you :).