# How can I restrict special characters in UITextField except dot and underscores?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How can I restrict special characters in a `UITextField` except dot and underscores?

I have tried the code snippet below, but without luck:

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
         NSCharacterSet *acceptedInput = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS];
        if (![[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:acceptedInput] count] > 1){
            NSLog(@"not allowed");
            return NO;
        }
        else{
            return YES;
        }
}
```

Comment: have you tried Regular expression ??

Comment: Best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7541846/1463604

Comment: **FOR SWIFT**... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26337774/294884

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Try code block given below, it worked fine for me.

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
let ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_"

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS).inverted
    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs).joined(separator: "")

    return (string == filtered)
}
```

**Objective C**

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
      NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

      NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

      return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: It should be `return ![string isEqualToString:filtered];`

Comment: @Fogh he is already using the `invertedSet` method so we don't need to include `!` in the return statement.

Comment: Seems a bit excessive to split something up, join it back together and then see if the two match when all you really need to do is count how many components there are after the split. If there's more than one, you already know there are unwanted characters.

Comment: Swift version here,

let ALLOWED_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_.";
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ALLOWED_CHARS);
        let filtered = string
            .components(separatedBy: set)
            .joined(separator: "");
        return filtered != string;
    }

Comment: @ElegyD, you should **add** Swift 4 version, not replace Swift 3 version with Swift 4.

Comment: What's the hell is going here? 1)`NSCharacterSet` from objective-c in swift while siwft has its own character set class; 2)`inverted` is totally extra - you can just use the opposite condition; 3)conversions string->array->string. Why not to replace your code in the `UITextField`'s delegate method with just one line: `return CharacterSet(charactersIn: string).isSubset(of: allowedCharacterSet)`? It is an example for **Swift 4.2**

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
NSCharacterSet  *set= [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet];
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[set invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

you can make your own set with

```
NSCharacterSet  *set= [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<all your symbols you want to ignore>"];
```

Comment: Change `symbolCharacterSet` to `ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS` and this will work how he wants....

Answer (score 4):

### **Swift 5 solution**

```
let ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let cs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS).inverted
        let filtered: String = (string.components(separatedBy: cs) as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "")
        return (string == filtered)
    }
```

Comment: Works in Swift 5.x too.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
let RISTRICTED_CHARACTERS = "'*=+[]\\|;:'\",<>/?%"
```

UITextField delegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn _: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: RISTRICTED_CHARACTERS)
    let inverted = set.inverted
    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: inverted).joined(separator: "")
    return filtered != string
}
```

Comment: This has a bug in it that the return bool should be == and not !=. Currently it will allow all characters except the restricted.

Comment: This doesn't work for case string == "" (for example clearing input)

Answer (score 3):

`NSString *Regex = @"[A-Za-z0-9^]*";`

`NSPredicate *TestResult = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex];`

`[TestResult evaluateWithObject:@"YourTestString"];`

Last return boolean value true/false

> In Method

```
+ (BOOL) validateSpecialCharactor: (NSString *) text {
NSString *Regex = @"[A-Za-z0-9^]*";
NSPredicate *TestResult = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex];
return [TestResult evaluateWithObject:text];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2.2 based on [Mrunal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558740/2868955):

```
let notAllowedCharacters = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_.";
func textField(
    textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String)
    -> Bool
{
    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: notAllowedCharacters);
    let inverted = set.invertedSet;

    let filtered = string
        .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(inverted)
        .joinWithSeparator("");
    return filtered == string;

}
```

Comment: Can i add 'if string == "" {return true}'?

Comment: @a.u.b I don't think the replacement string can ever be empty, but give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This may help you try this.. and let me know please

```
-(BOOL)isHaveSpecialChar:(NSString*)str{
NSString *customStr = @"~`!@#$%^&*()+=-/;:\"\'{}[]<>^?, ";
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:customStr];
BOOL isHaveSpecialChar = [[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet] isEqualToString:@""];
return !isHaveSpecialChar;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong - it will only return `YES` if every character in `str` is a character in `customStr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
func  textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")
    let inverted = set.inverted;

    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: inverted).joined(separator: "")
    return filtered == string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let cs = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs).joined(separator: "")
    return (string == filtered)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"___asdf.SHiv._.l.asg.  g.g._ASdgASG_.......asfgads.g.   .._____fdgdsfghsdfgh";

    str= [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@""];
    str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    str=[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];

    if ([str isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"valid");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"invalid");
    }
```

Comment: This is an extremely roundabout. Regular expressions are built for exactly this kind of thing.