# How to disallow special characters but allow Asian/Middle Eastern characters in a UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am using a `UITextField` for users to enter usernames, and would like to restrict special characters except for periods and underscores. I was initially set on using the [solution from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557925/ios-how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-uitextfield-except-dot-and-underscores), until I realized that I do not want to restrict to only alpha-numeric characters, but also allow Asian and Middle Eastern languages characters as well. Is there a way that I would be able to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Update:

Per rmaddy's suggestion, here is what I am presently using:

```
- (BOOL)userNameIsAcceptable: (NSString *)userNameInputted
{
    NSCharacterSet *userNameAcceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSString *filteredUserName = [[userNameInputted componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:userNameAcceptedInput] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog(@"The filtered result %@", filteredUserName);

    return [userNameAcceptedInput isEqual:filteredUserName];
}
```

Comment: What are special characters ? That's very ambiguous.

Comment: Special characters are non alphanumeric characters like "!", "#", "~", and etc. Since my goal is to limit these special characters in the creation of usernames, I thought it was ok to not specifically identify what these special characters are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the solution from the other question but instead of building the character set from the fixed letters, use the standard `NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question with the code I am using, but get the error `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFCharacterSet length]:` when I set it to `NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet`

Comment: You're using `characterSetWithCharactersInString:` and passing a character set (not a string). Get rid of your outer NSCharacterSet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe testing unicode chars from strings manually in loop against ranges containing unicode sets you need?
I did quick check, and it seems that unicode sets of Japanese letters are usually densely packed, except some special characters - I've looked here http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml but I guess similar should be valid to other languages as well.