# How to Validate Symbol Characterset in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscharacterset

Why is it taking `range.length` `nil`. I entered text `Demo@123`. In this special character is their but length will taking `nil`.

```
NSRange rang = [textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];

if ( !rang.length ) {
    return NO;  // no specialCharacter
}
```

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557925/ios-how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-uitextfield-except-dot-and-underscores

Answer (score 0):

NSRange is not an object, it's a struct. Lose the `*` character.

```
NSRange rang = ...
```

not

```
NSRange *rang = ...
```

You should be getting a warning for this.

Okey, going through the Unicode tables, it seems that `@` is not a symbol character. It is categorized as punctuation (`[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]`).

Comment: @ not consider as a symbolCharacterSet it is only reason for giving nil .