# How to limit length and special characters of UItextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm able to limit the length using the code below, but I can't seem to find a way to also limit special characters.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
let newLength = count(textField.text.utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length
if (textField.placeholder == "USERNAME")
{
    //Also limit special characters here
    return newLength <= 15 // Bool
}
```

characters I want allowed:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_.

I tried following this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557925/how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-uitextfield-except-dot-and-underscores)   but its in objective C and I'm having trouble merging it with my current 15 character limit code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to regex, you can first get all the allowed characters into a set:

```
 var charactesAllowed = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."
 var charactersSet = [Character](charactesAllowed)
```

then try to see if the most recently typed charactes is in this array

```
var newCharacter = //whatever the character is, ex: "A"
if(contains(charactersSet, newCharacter))
{
    println("Allowed")
    // Add it into the label text
}
```

Comment: I used this as a reference and it led me to what I was looking for.  I had to create an extension for contains

Answer (score -3):

```
let  ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"


if textField == textFieldNumber{
            let characterSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS).inverted
            maxLength = 11
            let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
            let newString: NSString =
                currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
            let filter = string.components(separatedBy: characterSet).joined(separator:"")
            return ((string == filter) && newString.length <= maxLength!)
        }
```