# How to restrict certain characters in UITextField in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, uitextfield

I am creating a trivia application that asks for a username on start up. I'd like to make it impossible to use characters such as #$@!^& etc (also including "space"). I took a look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557925/how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-uitextfield-except-dot-and-underscores) but it is written entirely in Objective-C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added answer to to original question that uses Swift.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4 iOS 11.2.x based on using an extension, tests to see if a string is a valid hex number in this example.

```
extension String {

var containsValidCharacter: Bool {
    guard self != "" else { return true }
    let hexSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890ABCDEFabcdef")
    let newSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: self)
    return hexSet.isSuperset(of: newSet)
  }
}
```

You use it like with the UITextFieldDelegate.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return (string.containsValidCharacter)
}
```

Although I read in an earlier post that CharacterSets do not support characters that are composed of more than one Unicode.Scalar; so use with caution I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're explicitly asking for Swift, I've translated the top asnwer in the linked question.

```
let notAllowedCharacters = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_.";

func textField(
    textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String)
    -> Bool
{
    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: notAllowedCharacters);
    let inverted = set.invertedSet;

    let filtered = string
        .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(inverted)
        .joinWithSeparator("");
    return filtered != string;

}
```

Comment: Can't break that semicolon habit

Answer (score 2):

```
internal func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
     if let text = string{
           if text == "#" || text == "$" || text == "!"{ \\and so on
              return false
           }
     }
     return true
}
```

Comment: Assumes replacement string is a single character, but it can be more when pasting a string

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.3

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let characters = ["#", "$", "!", "&","@"]
        for character in characters{
            if string == character{
                print("This characters are not allowed")
                return false
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Assumes replacement string is a single character but can be more if pasting

Answer (score 1):

So this is probably the most robust way to **restrict Spaces**. Using this user won't be able to **Paste/Type** **Whitespaces**

This is how you can Implement using **Swift 3**.

Add below mentioned `extension` snippet to a Swift file;

```
extension String {

var containsWhitespace: Bool {
    for scalar in unicodeScalars {
        switch scalar.value {
        case 0x20:
            return true
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

In your `ViewController` Swift file drag out your **Editing Changed** Instance and a **Referencing Outlet** of `UITextField` from Storyboard, the one mentioned in picture below:

[image]

Use the dragged Instances as mentioned below:

Referencing Outlet as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
```

and Editing Changed as:

```
 @IBAction func textChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if (textField.text!.containsWhitespace) == true {
        print("Restrict/Delete Whitespace")
        emailField.deleteBackward()
    } else {
        print("If Its not Whitespace, Its allowed.")
    }
}
```

This will **detect and remove whitespace** as soon as user tries to **type/paste** it.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 iOS 11.2.x based on using an extension, tests to see if a string is a valid hex number in this example.

extension String {

```
var containsValidCharacter: Bool {
    guard self != "" else { return true }
    let hexSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890ABCDEFabcdef")
    let newSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: self)
    return hexSet.isSuperset(of: newSet)
  }
}
```

You use it like with the UITextFieldDelegate.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return (string.containsValidCharacter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift : 3 and a different approach:

Add a target function for the text field change in your viewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
 }
```

in the target function, simply detect the entered char and replace it with blank. I have tested it and it prevents the user from entering any non desirable characters in the text field.

```
 func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {

    if let textInField = textField.text{
        if let lastChar = textInField.characters.last{

            //here include more characters which you don't want user to put in the text field
            if(lastChar == "*")
            {

                textField.text  = textInField.substring(to: textInField.index(before: textInField.endIndex))

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what @Evdzhan Mustafa said. You want to add a return statement in case the string is empty. Without it you won't be able to delete your text. Modified Code Below:

Swift 3 Version

```
let notAllowedCharacters = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_.";

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty{
        return true
    }

    print("String: \(string)")
    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: notAllowedCharacters);
    let inverted = set.inverted;

    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: inverted).joined(separator: "")
    print("String Filtered: \(filtered)")
    return filtered != string;
}
```

Comment: lose those semicolons

Comment: Had the idea that regex might be an easier way to filter the characters. Changed the models here to use regex instead. The result feels a lot more flexible.

Comment: Swift 3 examples with regex

Check for 0-9:
            `if !(string.range(of:"^[0-9]+$", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
            {
                valid = false
            }`

Check for 0-9, A-Z:
            `if !(string.range(of:"^[0-9A-Z]+$", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
            {
                valid = false
            }`