# Restrict the characters that can be entered in a uitextfield in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I would like to be able to restrict the characters that can be entered into a textfield, for instance I want to restrict to only 1-5 numbers (1,2,3, and 5) and if the user enters a number greater than 5, I want the textField to do nothing.

I have seen how to restrict the length but I couldn't find anything for restricting certain character as I'm describing above.

I tried using the `editingQtyFieldChanged` but it doesn't quite do what I want.

```
myField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserInputViewController.fieldChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func fieldChanged(){
    let number = Int(myField.text!)

    if number < 2{
        print("Number not allowed")
    }
}
```

Restrict to only numbers 1-5 in a uitextfield in Swift?

EDIT: Here is my solution, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925882/how-to-restrict-certain-characters-in-uitextfield-in-swift/40229568#40229568) thread.

```
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let numbers = ["6","7","8", "9"]
        for number in numbers{
            if string == number{
                return false
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: What is `editingQtyFieldChanged`? There's no such event documented (at least for Swift 3).

Comment: My bad, I typed the wrong method.

Answer (score 5):

I do this as a string extension

```
extension String {

   var containsValidCharacter: Bool {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "12345")
        let range = (self as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    }
}
```

And then in your `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    return !string.containsValidCharacter
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Nice solution, only is there no reason to invert `!` before returning and does the `shouldChangeCharactersInRage` function also block a backspace. In order to fix this I had to insert  `guard string != "" else { return true }`  before `return string.containsValidCharacter`

Answer (score 1):

In the [textFieldDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting) delegate, parse the text and convert it to a number. If the number isn't within your range, then set the text to its previous value or take whatever action is appropriate.