# How to prevent username textfield for not using whitespace or special characters swift 3.0

Tags: swift, uitextfield, textfield, removing-whitespace

I'm looking for way to make username text field for not accepting whitespace or special characters such as "/><,=+-|}{[])(*&^%$#!@~.. etc" for swift 3.0

I searched on internet anything that if I insert a username with whitespace or special characters to delete it or replace it.

Any help ?

Comment: Wait. even if they use all those characters can't you simply take in the entered string and remove the undesired characters from it?

Comment: nitinsh99 I followed the answer of the quest, and still not have result.

Comment: unfortunately other users have closed off this question so I can't answer here but I have posted an answer for you under this question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41027512/1099142