# How to prevent users from entering '#' and empty space(' ') in UITextfield - swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to prevent users from entering the characters '#' and empty spaces (' ').  I have got as far as below (see code below) but not sure how to complete the rest ...

```
 class CreateTags: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

 /*** OUTLETS ***/
 @IBOutlet weak var inputTxtOutlet: UITextField!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
      self.inputTxtOutlet.delegate = self
 }

 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

 }
```

Comment: you want to prevent the special characters or the particular char's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need o implement following delegate method (as you already implemented)

**Set delegate**

```
yourtextField.delegate = self
```

**Delegate method**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string == "#" || string == " " {
        return false //disallow # and a space
    }
    return true

 }
```

> In another way you can do it as follow

**Create a constant that contains disallowed chars.**

```
 let disallowedChars = ["#", " "] //add more chars as per your need
```

**In delegate method check those chars...**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

      if disallowedChars.contains(string) {
        return false
      }

      return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **one-liner**. (Works for copy paste!)

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return !string.contains(where: {$0 == "#" || $0 == " "})
}
```

If you have a lot of restricted characters,

```
let restrictedCharacters: [Character] = [" ", "#", "?"]

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   return !(Set(string).intersection(Set(restrictedCharacters)).count > 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to be specific for `UITextfields`!

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

 if textField == inputTxtOutlet  {
       let myCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:" #")
       let output: String = string.trimmingCharacters(in: myCharSet.inverted)
       let isValid: Bool = (string == output)

        if isValid {
             return false
        } else {
             return true
                }
            }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let restrictedChars = ["#", "*", " "]

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   return  restrictedChars.contains(string) ? false : true 
}
```

Comment: This is the best and most concise solution

Comment: @sk123 did you try it with copy paste?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:-

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let characters = ["#", "$", "!", "&","@"]
    for character in characters{
        if string == character{
            print("This characters are not allowed")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

uses this [How to restrict certain characters in UITextField in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925882/how-to-restrict-certain-characters-in-uitextfield-in-swift) example

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {

   var containsValidCharacter: Bool {
   guard self != "" else { return true }
   let hexSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890ABCDEFabcdef")
   let newSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: self)
   return hexSet.isSuperset(of: newSet)

 }
}
```

You use it like with the UITextFieldDelegate.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
return (string.containsValidCharacter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your "shouldChangeCharactersIn" method with below code

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let characters = ["#", " "]
    for character in characters{
        if string == character{
            print("This characters are not allowed")
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```