# Limit UITextField input to numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How can I get limit the user's TextField input to numbers in Swift?

Comment: Are you using storyboards? If you are there is an option in the property inspector to only allow numeric characters

Comment: also useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/26337774/294884

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `UITextFieldDelegate`’s `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method to limit the user's input to numbers:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Create an `NSCharacterSet` set which includes everything *but* the digits
    let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet

    // At every character in this "inverseSet" contained in the string,
    // split the string up into components which exclude the characters
    // in this inverse set
    let components = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(inverseSet)

    // Rejoin these components
    let filtered = components.joinWithSeparator("")  // use join("", components) if you are using Swift 1.2

    // If the original string is equal to the filtered string, i.e. if no
    // inverse characters were present to be eliminated, the input is valid
    // and the statement returns true; else it returns false
    return string == filtered
}
```

---

Updated for Swift 3:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
    shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Create an `NSCharacterSet` set which includes everything *but* the digits
    let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted

    // At every character in this "inverseSet" contained in the string,
    // split the string up into components which exclude the characters
    // in this inverse set
    let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

    // Rejoin these components
    let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")  // use join("", components) if you are using Swift 1.2

    // If the original string is equal to the filtered string, i.e. if no
    // inverse characters were present to be eliminated, the input is valid
    // and the statement returns true; else it returns false
    return string == filtered  
}
```

Comment: `join("", components)` breaks in Swift 2.0, do `components.joinWithSeparator("")` instead.

Comment: pretty code. this is a model of how to write self-documenting code. and dat's the only code.

Comment: let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)
        
        // Rejoin these components
        let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")    for Swift 3

Comment: and what to do with those functions?

Comment: why you didn't mention `UITextFieldDelegate`??

Comment: @user924 Thanks for the suggestion. I’ll specifically mention UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: You can use just `joined()` since `separator` has a default value.

Comment: @LyndseyScott it's just would be easier for new iOS developers (I usually develop Android apps). p.s. checked your profile, you're awesome xD, A Girl, Former model, and now iOS developer:)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for a shorter answer, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594179/remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-swift) quite useful.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // remove non-numerics and compare with original string
    return string == string.filter("0123456789".contains)
}
```

Works in XCode 10.1, Swift 4.2

Answer (score 1):

> 1st you have to inherit the UITextViewDelegate class with you own
>   class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

> 2nd add an IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
```

> 3rd you have to assure this object is using

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   firstName.delegate = self
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == firstName {
                let allowedCharacters = "1234567890"
                let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
                let typedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
                let alphabet = allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: typedCharacterSet)
                let Range = range.length + range.location > (fnameTF.text?.count)!

        if Range == false && alphabet == false {
            return false
        }


        let NewLength = (fnameTF.text?.count)! + string.count - range.length
        return NewLength <= 10


      } else {
        return false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks good? But what is this "fnameTF.text?.count" referring too? And is missing a final return?

Comment: fnameTF is a textField and fnameTF.text?.count means we are counting textField characters. @user3069232

Comment: Ok, so the @IBOutlet firstName is actually called fnameTF?

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 10

Add **UITextFieldDelegate** to your class

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Then write this code in your **viewDidLoad()**

```
yourTF.delegate = self
```

Write this textfield delegate function

```
//MARK - UITextField Delegates
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //For numers
    if textField == yourTF {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789")//Here change this characters based on your requirement
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the iOS provides no such functionality where you can specify textfield to accept only numeric characters. The only way through would be, one of **UITextFieldDelegate** methods, which is as follows,

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

You need to implement the following method and intercept the entered character and either through the following regular expression

```
"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$"
```

or

```
[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]
```

you can find out whether the entered character is numeric and return **YES** if it matches the regular expression or character set else return **NO**.