# How to allow only certain set of numbers in a UITextfield in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift2

I am having a `UITextField` in which i get the month number as input. I am successful in limiting the no of characters to 2 in the UITextField. But i want users to enter only the values from `1 to 12` and none other than that. This has to be done simultaneously when the user types the numbers i.e in `func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool`. If i use a simple `if` condition to check the each character and return false in `else` part the textfield won't allow me to use clear or retype any other character. someone help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set keyboard type as Number Pad

add this

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {

    if let text = textField.text {

        let newStr = (text as NSString)
            .stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        if newStr.isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        let intvalue = Int(newStr)
        return (intvalue >= 0 && intvalue <= 12)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks this works great with my code`var length = (count(textField.text) + count(string) - range.length)` and returned as `return length < 3 && (intvalue > 0 && intvalue <= 12) ? true : false`

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant `return 1...12 ~= intvalue`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simultaneously by checking the TextField value inside shouldChangeCharactersInRange.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let inputStr = textField.text?.stringByAppendingString(string)
    let inputInt = Int(inputStr!)
    if inputInt > 0 && inputInt < 13 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: If the else part is executed and `false` is returned you cannot clear the text or reenter the text.

Comment: i'm not sure about your code, but i have checked it, the code above didn't do anything to neither block the user clear the text nor re enter text.

Comment: sorry my mistake. your code too works good and is very simple

Answer (score 2):

=> you can Define limite of char like this:-

```
#define NUMBERS_ONLY @"1234567890"

#define  CHARACTER_LIMIT 2
```

=> and based on define limit char you can use and try it below method :-

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  
    {

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT));

    }
```

Comment: this objective c code is nothing different than the swift answer above. it is just the objective c version with character limit . `var length = (count(textField.text) + count(string) - range.length)` and `return length < 3` this is the swift 1.2 for simple length constrain

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        // Create an `NSCharacterSet` set which includes everything *but* the digits
        let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet

        // At every character in this "inverseSet" contained in the string,
        // split the string up into components which exclude the characters
        // in this inverse set
        let components = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(inverseSet)

        // Rejoin these components
        let filtered = components.joinWithSeparator("")  // use join("", components) if you are using Swift 1.2

        // If the original string is equal to the filtered string, i.e. if no
        // inverse characters were present to be eliminated, the input is valid
        // and the statement returns true; else it returns false
        return string == filtered

}
```

see this link-- [Limit UITextField input to numbers in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215495/limit-uitextfield-input-to-numbers-in-swift)

Comment: add if condition in this function to check value of textfield is less then equal to 12 and greater than equal to 1.

Comment: I already tried this code it allows 13 to 99 too. also if i  use if condition and return false i can no longer edit the text field even backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this to set Limit the numbers and allow only numbers 0 to 9.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == mobileNumber {
        let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
        let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
        let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
        let length = (mobileNumber.text?.count)! + string.count - range.length
        return string == numberFiltered && length <= LIMIT
    }else if textField == userType {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post a more simplified answer based on the previous answers.

**Tested on Swift 5.1**

Considering that you already set `textField.keyboardType = .numberPad`, then you can do the following:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return true
        }
        let newStr = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        guard let intValue = Int(newStr) else {
            return true
        }
        return intValue <= maxNumber // maxNumber: replace with your max number
    }
```

You dont´need to validate that `intValue` is greater or equal to `0` because in `numberPad` you can NOT write negative values.