# Best way to force a text field to have a single word only in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `textfield`, where I ask a user for a single word.

What is the recommended way to not allow users to enter multiple words? My current solution is to implement `textField(shouldChangeCharactersInRange)` and not allow any spaces.

Is there a way that requires no code (i.e. change properties of the `textfield` in the storyboard)?

Comment: The way you have done it is the simplest way.

Comment: for more help see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649504/how-to-allow-only-certain-set-of-numbers-in-a-uitextfield-in-swift-2-0